# MKPinAnnotationView not moving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mkpinannotationview, google-geocoding-api

I have went through a few links here, not all of them, regarding `MKPinAnnotationView` pin, subclass, etc. I did some simple tutorials online and when I thought I could start on my application with the knowledge from the tutorials, I was wrong. :(

In my tutorial file, I managed to do a simple MKPinAnnotationView *pin. Set its properties, like `canShowCallOut = YES`, `draggable = YES`. I can drag the pin anywhere I want to and display the location its dropped at.

But when I created my new application, I did the same thing again. But the pin isn't moving, is there something I did wrong?

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomPlacemark class]])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:[annotation title]];
        newAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES; 
        newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES; // shows the black label when the pin is tapped
        newAnnotation.draggable = YES;
//      newAnnotation.enabled = YES;
        newAnnotation.tag = tag;
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", [annotation title], [annotation subtitle]);
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        NSLog(@"Created annotation at: %f %f", ((CustomPlacemark*)annotation).coordinate.latitude, ((CustomPlacemark*)annotation).coordinate.longitude);

        [newAnnotation addObserver:self
                        forKeyPath:@"selected"
                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                           context:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"];

        [newAnnotation autorelease];
        tag++;
        NSLog(@"ååååååååå %@", appDelegate.fml);
        return newAnnotation;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look

http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/252784277/mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with-callout-info

I'm looking for the same problem.